# How do you stop Console from popping up automatically in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a web application running in Eclipse with Tomcat.  It has a few errors that make the console popup every few seconds.  How do I stop it from automatically popping up and taking focus?

Answer (score 182, accepted):

There are two buttons on the console toolbar at the bottom that allow you to take focus (or not)...one for stdout, one for stderr. I have an image with the buttons circled.

[image]

Comment: All the time looking at the console and never seeing those icons!

Comment: I don't see those icons in Eclipse Helios

Comment: For newer versions of Eclipse, go to Preferences > Run/Debug > Console and uncheck "Show when program writes to standard out" and "Show when program writes to standard error".

Comment: Works for most cases, but whenever I run JUnit tests, the console view in Mars steals focus from the JUnit view as soon as a breakpoint is hit and again when the test finishes (even if there is absolutely no output to the console). Only solution (well, workaround) I've been able to find is to keep the two tabs in different tab stacks.

Comment: This also does not work for python scripts launched with EASE.

Answer (score 28):

There are two icons - "Show Console When X changes" in the console view. Unselect those.

Comment: I don't seem to have these icons.... See http://i.stack.imgur.com/61Jgx.png . How do you make them appear?

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done in Preferences

Windows > Preferences > Run/Debug > Console

uncheck "Show when program writes to standard out" and/or "Show when program writes to standard error".

Answer (score 0):

In poped up window.

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbaR3.png

2.New console view.

3.close the popped up window.