# Eclipse console pop up automatically when it finds an error

Tags: eclipse, console

When I type something wrong and save, eclipse marks my error.

But in the meanwhile, the console view pops up and tells me [2011-04-04 22:27:21 - Sudoku] Error in an XML file: aborting build. or blahblah. I don't want it.

I find an answer here [How do you stop Console from popping up automatically in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462520/how-do-you-stop-console-from-popping-up-automatically-in-eclipse), but my console view has not such two icons.

Comment: 3.6. I try to disable "show when program writes to standard error" in preference->run/debug/console. Doesn't work.

Comment: It's a strange problem. Whatever I change in preference->run/debug->console, it doesn't work. I change the color of output, but stdout is still black, stderr is still red.

Answer (score 14):

What version of Eclipse are you using? In Helios, you can accomplish the same thing as in the answer you linked.

1. Go to `Preferences -> Run/Debug -> Console`
2. Uncheck `Show when program writes to standard out` and
   `Show when program writes to standard error`

Comment: I uncheck them both. the console pops up, still.

Comment: You could disable automatic builds entirely.